# Multicollinearity on multiple dependent variables

Tags: r, multicollinearity

Consider the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(car)

a <- c( 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 100, 11)
b <- c(5, 6, 7, 80, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14)
c <- c(15, 16, 175, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24)

x <- c(17,18,50,15,64,15,3,5,6,9)
y <- c(55,66,99,83,64,51,23,64,89,101)
z <- c(98,78,56,21,45,34,61,98,45,64)

abc <- data.frame(cbind(a,b,c))
```

Firstly, I run a regression and values abc with xyz as follows (This went according to plan):

```
dep_vars <- as.matrix(abc)
lm <- lm(dep_vars ~ x + y + z, data = abc)
```

From here, I want to get the variance inflation factor using the `vif()` function:

```
vif(lm)
```

But then I get an error that says `Error in if (names(coefficients(mod)[1]) == "(Intercept)") { : argument is of length zero`.
Can anybody help me understand where I went wrong? Or is there an alternative?

Comment: `library(car)

a <- c( 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 100, 11)
b <- c(5, 6, 7, 80, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14)
c <- c(15, 16, 175, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24)
d <- c(90, 92, 94, 96, 98, 100, 102, 103, 100, 90)
e <- c(27, 28, 50, 15, 64, 25, 3, 5, 6, 9)

abcde <- data.frame(cbind(a, b, c, d, e))
lm <- lm(as.matrix(d, e) ~ a + b + c, data = abcde)
vif(lm)`

Comment: Kgosi, is this what you were after?

Comment: Yes, I guess the problem was my variables weren't all in one data frame?

Comment: @Isaiah I've still got the same problem though?

Comment: Just tried a couple of times and worked for me. Perhaps you need to clear your environment. I'd also restart R.

Comment: Voting to close as not-reproducible.